# How to analyze the length of time a specific function runs in R

Tags: performance, r, profiling, benchmarking, bioinformatics

I just got a gig to help speed up a program in R by improving the efficiency of the algorithms used to calculate data. There are many loops that do different calculations, and I'm wondering which loops end up using the most resources. I want to know how can I count the amount of time it takes for a loop to completely finish. I can use that information to figure out which algorithms to optimize, or even to write a C extension that will handle the calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

- `Sys.time()` or `system.time()`
- The `rbenchmark` package
- The `microbenchmark` package
- Or a profiler (e.g. `?RProf`)

Comment: Do you list them in order ?

Comment: For the first bullet point, you can use `beg <- Sys.time(); { MyCode() }; Sys.time() - beg` _or_ `system.time({ MyCode() })` which is probably preferable.

Answer (score 2):

I use `Rprof` to tell where to look.
It generates a file of stack samples, and I just look at a small number of those, like 10, chosen randomly.
Or I just make the time between samples large enough so I don't get too many samples to begin with.

There are 2 reasons this works.

1) By actually examining individual stack samples, with your own eyes, you can see problems that simple statistics don't expose, because by looking at the stack, you can see the reasons why things are being done. That tells you if you could get rid of it, and that's the essential information.

2) If you see such a pattern of activity that you could improve, you only have to see it on *more than one sample* to know it's worth fixing.
All the extra samples, if they mean you cannot do (1), are actually detrimental.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of using benchmark from [another SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705533/does-the-by-function-make-growing-list/13707163#13707163) which compared using `tapply` vs `by` vs `data.table`: *Edited as per on comments*

```
library(rbenchmark)  

           # Different tests being compared
benchmark( using.tapply = tapply(x[, 1], x[, "f"], mean),
           using.by = by(x[, 1], x[, "f"], mean), 
           using.dtable = dt[,mean(col1),by=key(dt)]), 

           # Number of reps. How results are.
           replications = 250, order = "relative"
          )   

#------------------------#
#         RESULTS        # 
#------------------------#


#   COMPARING data.table VS tapply VS by   #
#------------------------------------------#
#             test elapsed relative
#   2  using.dtable   0.168    1.000
#   1  using.tapply   2.396   14.262
#   3      using.by   8.566   50.988
```

Comment: what's with all the `expression`s?

Comment: @ GSee. I like to save them as expressions so that I can easily change the input once across all my tests. (Also, I find it gives a nicer output in the `test` column)

Comment: `benchmark(using.tapply=tappyl(x[, 1], x[, "f"], mean), using.by=by(x[, 1], x[, "f"], mean), using.dtable=dt[, mean(col1),by=key(dt)], replications=10, order='relative')` ... whatever `x` and `dt` are

Comment: Just name the `...` arguments: `benchmark(using.tapply=tapply(x[, 1], x[, "f"], mean))`.

Comment: yes of course.  But if I have 10~15 tests I am comparing, taking the actual code in and out is a lot more cumbersome than using a variable.  Wrapping them in `expression` I find moves more quickly. Is there any downside to using `expression`? (ie, any risk to getting the wrong results?)

Comment: Put each test on its own line.  Then you can easily add/remove them.  The biggest problem I see with using `expression` is that you're probably going to confuse others who look at your code.

Comment: Plus `expression` isn't even the right function to use here - `quote` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @hadley: can you elaborate on why that is?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta `expression` produces (basically) a lists of calls.  Expression lists are rarely needed outside of special cases, such as sourcing a file, and you're best off using the simplest quoted call, as produced by `quote`.

Comment: @hadley, please correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that `expression` is indeed the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713116/benchmarking-using-expression-quote-or-neither

Comment: @RicardoSaporta that sounds like a bug with rbenchmark to me.