# Benchmarking: using `expression` `quote` or neither

Tags: r, expression, benchmarking

Generally, when I run benchmarks, I wrap my statements in `expression`. 
Recently, it was suggested to either (a) not do so or (b) use `quote` instead of expression.

I find two advantages to wrapping the statements:

- compared to entire statements, they are more easily swapped out.
- I can lapply over a list of inputs, and compare those results

However, in exploring the different methods, I noticed a discrepency between the three methods (wrapping in `expression`, wrapping in `quote`, or not wrapping at all)

**The question is:**
  Why the discrepency? 
  (it appears that wrapping in `quote` does not actually evaluate the call.)

### EXAMPLE:

```
# SAMPLE DATA
  mat <-  matrix(sample(seq(1e6), 4^2*1e4, T), ncol=400) 

# RAW EXPRESSION TO BENCHMARK IS: 
  # apply(mat, 2, mean)

# WRAPPED EXPRESSION: 
  expr <- expression(apply(mat, 2, mean))
  quot <- quote(apply(mat, 2, mean))

# BENCHMARKS
  benchmark(raw=apply(mat, 2, mean), expr, quot)[, -(7:8)]
  #    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
  #  2 expr          100   1.269       NA     1.256    0.019
  #  3 quot          100   0.000       NA     0.001    0.000
  #  1  raw          100   1.494       NA     1.286    0.021


# BENCHMARKED INDIVIDUALLY 
  benchmark(raw=apply(mat, 2, mean))[, -(7:8)]
  benchmark(expr)[, -(7:8)]
  benchmark(quot)[, -(7:8)]

  # results
  #    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
  #  1  raw          100   1.274        1      1.26    0.018
  #    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
  #  1 expr          100   1.476        1     1.342    0.021
  #    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
  #  1 quot          100   0.006        1     0.006    0.001
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is that `quote` does not produce an expression but a `call`, so within the call to benchmark, there is no expression to evaluate.

If you evaluate the `call it will actually get evaluated, and the timings are reasonable.

```
class(quot)
[1] "call"
>class(expr)
[1] "expression"


 benchmark(raw=apply(mat, 2, mean), expr, eval(quot))[, -(7:8)]
        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
3 eval(quot)          100    0.76    1.000      0.77        0
2       expr          100    0.83    1.092      0.83        0
1        raw          100    0.78    1.026      0.78        0
```

In general, I tend to create a function that contains the call / process  I wish to benchmark. Note that it is good practice to include things like assigning the result to a value.

eg

```
 raw <- function() {x <- apply(mat, 2, mean)}
```

In which case it looks like that there is a slight improvement by `eval(quote(...))`.

```
benchmark(raw(), eval(quote(raw()))

                test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self 
2 eval(quote(raw()))          100    0.76    1.000      0.75     0.01        
1              raw()          100    0.80    1.053      0.80     0.00
```

But often these small differences can be due to overheads in functions and may not reflect how the performance scales to larger problems. See the many questions with benchmarkings of `data.table` solutions, using a small number of replications but big data may better reflect performance.

Comment: Thanks mnel. Are there any differences (ie advantages/disadvantages) to using one vs the other?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, I've added a bit more of a my understanding of benchmarking.

Comment: Specifically, your last statement is exactly how I began to use `expression` (as wrapping the statements in a function may not be as representative)

Comment: I think you're getting tripped up by R's inconsistent use of the word expression.  Informally, an unevaluated expression is something like `a + b`, or `f(g(1,3), 4)` - but technically, those are calls.  The output of expression is a list of calls, which is needed only when sourcing in external file.