# R use ddply or aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I have a data frame with 3 columns: custId, saleDate, DelivDateTime.

```
> head(events22)
     custId            saleDate      DelivDate
1 280356593 2012-11-14 14:04:59 11/14/12 17:29
2 280367076 2012-11-14 17:04:44 11/14/12 20:48
3 280380097 2012-11-14 17:38:34 11/14/12 20:45
4 280380095 2012-11-14 20:45:44 11/14/12 23:59
5 280380095 2012-11-14 20:31:39 11/14/12 23:49
6 280380095 2012-11-14 19:58:32 11/15/12 00:10
```

Here's the dput:

```
> dput(events22)
structure(list(custId = c(280356593L, 280367076L, 280380097L, 
280380095L, 280380095L, 280380095L, 280364279L, 280364279L, 280398506L, 
280336395L, 280364376L, 280368458L, 280368458L, 280368456L, 280368456L, 
280364225L, 280391721L, 280353458L, 280387607L, 280387607L), 
    saleDate = structure(c(1352901899.215, 1352912684.484, 1352914714.971, 
    1352925944.429, 1352925099.247, 1352923112.636, 1352922476.55, 
    1352920666.968, 1352915226.534, 1352911135.077, 1352921349.592, 
    1352911494.975, 1352910529.86, 1352924755.295, 1352907511.476, 
    1352920108.577, 1352906160.883, 1352905925.134, 1352916810.309, 
    1352916025.673), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    DelivDate = c("11/14/12 17:29", "11/14/12 20:48", "11/14/12 20:45", 
    "11/14/12 23:59", "11/14/12 23:49", "11/15/12 00:10", "11/14/12 23:35", 
    "11/14/12 22:59", "11/14/12 20:53", "11/14/12 19:52", "11/14/12 23:01", 
    "11/14/12 19:47", "11/14/12 19:42", "11/14/12 23:31", "11/14/12 23:33", 
    "11/14/12 22:45", "11/14/12 18:11", "11/14/12 18:12", "11/14/12 19:17", 
    "11/14/12 19:19")), .Names = c("custId", "saleDate", "DelivDate"
), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to find the `DelivDate` for the most recent `saleDate` for each `custId`.

I can do that using plyr::ddply like this:

```
dd1 <-ddply(events22, .(custId),.inform = T, function(x){
x[x$saleDate == max(x$saleDate),"DelivDate"]
})
```

My question is whether there is a faster way to do this as the ddply method is a bit time consuming (the full data set is ~ 400k lines).  I've looked at using `aggregate()` but don't know how to get a value other than the one I'm sorting by.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here's the benchmark results for 10k lines @ 10 iterations:

```
      test replications elapsed relative user.self
2   AGG2()           10    5.96    1.000      5.93
1   AGG1()           10   20.87    3.502     20.75
5 DATATABLE()        10   61.32        1     60.31
3  DDPLY()           10   80.04   13.430     79.63
4 DOCALL()           10   90.43   15.173     88.39
```

EDIT2 :
While being quickest AGG2() doesn't give the correct answer.

```
    > head(agg2)
     custId            saleDate      DelivDate
1 280336395 2012-11-14 16:38:55 11/14/12 19:52
2 280353458 2012-11-14 15:12:05 11/14/12 18:12
3 280356593 2012-11-14 14:04:59 11/14/12 17:29
4 280364225 2012-11-14 19:08:28 11/14/12 22:45
5 280364279 2012-11-14 19:47:56 11/14/12 23:35
6 280364376 2012-11-14 19:29:09 11/14/12 23:01
> agg2 <- AGG2()
> head(agg2)
     custId      DelivDate
1 280336395 11/14/12 17:29
2 280353458 11/14/12 17:29
3 280356593 11/14/12 17:29
4 280364225 11/14/12 17:29
5 280364279 11/14/12 17:29
6 280364376 11/14/12 17:29
> agg2 <- DDPLY()
> head(agg2)
     custId             V1
1 280336395 11/14/12 19:52
2 280353458 11/14/12 18:12
3 280356593 11/14/12 17:29
4 280364225 11/14/12 22:45
5 280364279 11/14/12 23:35
6 280364376 11/14/12 23:01
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I, too, would recommend `data.table` here, but since you asked for an `aggregate` solution, here is one which combines `aggregate` and `merge` to get all the columns:

```
merge(events22, aggregate(saleDate ~ custId, events22, max))
```

Or just `aggregate` if you only want the "custId" and "DelivDate" columns:

```
aggregate(list(DelivDate = events22$saleDate), 
          list(custId = events22$custId),
          function(x) events22[["DelivDate"]][which.max(x)])
```

Finally, here's an option using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select custId, DelivDate, max(saleDate) `saleDate` 
      from events22 group by custId")
```

---

#### Benchmarks

I'm not a benchmarking or `data.table` expert, but it surprised me that `data.table` is not faster here. *My suspicion is that the results would be quite different on a larger dataset*, say for instance, your 400k lines one. Anyway, here's some benchmarking code [modeled after @mnel's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13713220/1270695) so you can do some tests on your actual dataset for future reference.

```
library(rbenchmark)
```

First, set up your functions for what you want to benchmark.

```
DDPLY <- function() { 
  x <- ddply(events22, .(custId), .inform = T, 
             function(x) {
               x[x$saleDate == max(x$saleDate),"DelivDate"]}) 
}
DATATABLE <- function() { x <- dt[, .SD[which.max(saleDate), ], by = custId] }
AGG1 <- function() { 
  x <- merge(events22, aggregate(saleDate ~ custId, events22, max)) }
AGG2 <- function() { 
  x <- aggregate(list(DelivDate = events22$saleDate), 
                 list(custId = events22$custId),
                 function(x) events22[["DelivDate"]][which.max(x)]) }
SQLDF <- function() { 
  x <- sqldf("select custId, DelivDate, max(saleDate) `saleDate` 
             from events22 group by custId") }
DOCALL <- function() {
  do.call(rbind, 
          lapply(split(events22, events22$custId), function(x){
            x[which.max(x$saleDate), ]
          })
  )
}
```

Second, do the benchmarking.

```
benchmark(DDPLY(), DATATABLE(), AGG1(), AGG2(), SQLDF(), DOCALL(), 
          order = "elapsed")[1:5]
#          test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 4      AGG2()          100   0.285    1.000     0.284
# 3      AGG1()          100   0.891    3.126     0.896
# 6    DOCALL()          100   1.202    4.218     1.204
# 2 DATATABLE()          100   1.251    4.389     1.248
# 1     DDPLY()          100   1.254    4.400     1.252
# 5     SQLDF()          100   2.109    7.400     2.108
```

Comment: AGG2 may be fast because you're not returning all columns.

Comment: @TylerRinker, neither does `ddply` from the OPs current method.

Comment: Yes, in that linked question @mnel was showing how _not_ to benchmark and explained why setting replications to 100 on a small dataset results in significant differences of insignificant times. The task being timed here takes between 0.00285 and 0.021 seconds. If that matters then the task should probably be coded in a compiled language. Also, `dt[, .SD[which.max(saleDate), ], by = custId]` is not the fastest way of doing that in data.table but we hope to optimize it in future to turn that into the fastest way automatically, since it is the most natural.

Comment: @AnandaMahto If you create some random data for the benchmark (e.g. using `rnorm` and `sample`) you can easily play with variables like: the unique number of levels of a factor, the total size of the dataset etc.

Comment: Exactly, as Paul says, replicate the data to make it large. Usually needs to be quite a bit larger than L2 cache, say 100MB minimum, 1GB+ better. Many people have 8GB RAM and some have servers with 128GB RAM or more. As ?data.table says, large RAM is really where the biggest performance gains of data.table are.

Comment: But we are concerned about call overhead too, and that's why we added `set()` as a loopable `:=`, for example. Good point about time to tweak. This is why optimization was added and the old tricks needed to make `mean()` as fast as `sum()` are no longer required. Would like to do more of that, definitely.

Comment: Actually I'd forgotten but this one is already a feature request: [FR#2330 Optimize .SDi query to keep the elegance but make it faster unchanged.](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2330&group_id=240&atid=978).

Comment: I posted results for 10k lines above.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: AGG2 is fastest but doesn't seem to be returning the correct values.  See above EDIT2.

Answer (score 7):

The fastest between `ddply` and `aggregate`, I suppose would be `aggregate`, especially on huge data as you have. However, the fastest would be `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(events22)
dt[, .SD[which.max(saleDate),], by=custId]
```

From `?data.table`: `.SD` is a `data.table` containing the subset of x's
          Data for each group, excluding the group column(s).

Comment: Good call on `data.table` here.

Answer (score 3):

This should be pretty fast but `data.table` is likely faster:

```
do.call(rbind, 
    lapply(split(events22, events22$custId), function(x){
        x[which.max(x$saleDate), ]
    })
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a much faster `data.table` function:

```
DATATABLE <- function() { 
  dt <- data.table(events, key=c('custId', 'saleDate'))
  dt[, maxrow := 1:.N==.N, by = custId]
  return(dt[maxrow==TRUE, list(custId, DelivDate)])
}
```

Note that this function creates a `data.table` and sorts the data, which is a step you'd only need to perform once.  If you remove this step (perhaps you have a multi-step data processing pipeline, and create the `data.table` once, as a first step), the function is more than twice as fast.

I also modified all the previous functions to return the result, for easier comparison:

```
DDPLY <- function() { 
  return(ddply(events, .(custId), .inform = T, 
               function(x) {
                 x[x$saleDate == max(x$saleDate),"DelivDate"]}))
}
AGG1 <- function() { 
  return(merge(events, aggregate(saleDate ~ custId, events, max)))}

SQLDF <- function() { 
  return(sqldf("select custId, DelivDate, max(saleDate) `saleDate` 
             from events group by custId"))}
DOCALL <- function() {
  return(do.call(rbind, 
                 lapply(split(events, events$custId), function(x){
                   x[which.max(x$saleDate), ]
                 })
  ))
}
```

Here's the results for 10k rows, repeated 10 times:

```
library(rbenchmark)
library(plyr)
library(data.table)
library(sqldf)
events <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:500, function(x) events22))
events$custId <- sample(1:nrow(events), nrow(events))

benchmark(a <- DDPLY(), b <- DATATABLE(), c <- AGG1(), d <- SQLDF(),
 e <- DOCALL(), order = "elapsed", replications=10)[1:5]

              test replications elapsed relative user.self
2 b <- DATATABLE()           10    0.13    1.000      0.13
4     d <- SQLDF()           10    0.42    3.231      0.41
3      c <- AGG1()           10   12.11   93.154     12.03
1     a <- DDPLY()           10   32.17  247.462     32.01
5    e <- DOCALL()           10   56.05  431.154     55.85
```

Since all the functions return their results, we can verify they all return the same answer:

```
c <- c[order(c$custId),]
dim(a); dim(b); dim(c); dim(d); dim(e)
all(a$V1==b$DelivDate)
all(a$V1==c$DelivDate)
all(a$V1==d$DelivDate)
all(a$V1==e$DelivDate)
```

/Edit: On the smaller, 20 row dataset, `data.table` is still the fastest, but by a thinner margin:

```
              test replications elapsed relative user.self
2 b <- DATATABLE()          100    0.22    1.000      0.22
3      c <- AGG1()          100    0.42    1.909      0.42
5    e <- DOCALL()          100    0.48    2.182      0.49
1     a <- DDPLY()          100    0.55    2.500      0.55
4     d <- SQLDF()          100    1.00    4.545      0.98
```

/Edit2: If we remove the `data.table` creation from the function we get the following results:

```
dt <- data.table(events, key=c('custId', 'saleDate'))
DATATABLE2 <- function() { 
  dt[, maxrow := 1:.N==.N, by = custId]
  return(dt[maxrow==TRUE, list(custId, DelivDate)])
}
benchmark(a <- DDPLY(), b <- DATATABLE2(), c <- AGG1(), d <- SQLDF(),
           e <- DOCALL(), order = "elapsed", replications=10)[1:5]
              test replications elapsed relative user.self
2 b <- DATATABLE()           10    0.09    1.000      0.08
4     d <- SQLDF()           10    0.41    4.556      0.39
3      c <- AGG1()           10   11.73  130.333     11.67
1     a <- DDPLY()           10   31.59  351.000     31.50
5    e <- DOCALL()           10   55.05  611.667     54.91
```