# Aggregate by factor levels, keeping other variables in the resulting data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the minimum values of a numeric column for each level of a factor, while keeping values of another factor in the resulting data frame.

```
# dummy data
dat <- data.frame(
    code = c("HH11", "HH45", "JL03", "JL03", "JL03", "HH11"), 
    index = c("023434", "3377477", "3388595", "3377477", "1177777", "023434"), 
    value = c(24.1, 37.2, 78.9, 45.9, 20.0, 34.6)
    )
```

The result I want is the minimum of `value` for each level of `code`, keeping `index` in the resulting data frame.

```
# result I want:
#   code value    index
# 1 HH11  24.1   023434
# 2 HH45  37.2  3377477
# 3 JL03  20.0  1177777


# ddply attempt
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, ~ code, summarise, val = min(value))
#   code   val
# 1 HH11  24.1
# 2 HH45  37.2
# 3 JL03  20.0


# base R attempt
aggregate(value ~ code, dat, min)
#   code value
# 1 HH11  24.1
# 2 HH45  37.2
# 3 JL03  20.0
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use `merge` on result of `aggregate` and original `data.frame`

```
merge(aggregate(value ~ code, dat, min), dat, by = c("code", "value"))
##   code value   index
## 1 HH11  24.1  023434
## 2 HH45  37.2 3377477
## 3 JL03  20.0 1177777
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to show that there's always multiple ways to skin a cat:

Using `ave` to get the indexes of the minimum rows in each group:

```
dat[which(ave(dat$value,dat$code,FUN=function(x) x==min(x))==1),]

#  code   index value
#1 HH11  023434  24.1
#2 HH45 3377477  37.2
#5 JL03 1177777  20.0
```

This method also has the potential benefit of returning multiple rows per `code` group in the instance of multiple values being the minimum.

And another method using `by`:

```
do.call(rbind,
  by(dat, dat$code, function(x) cbind(x[1,c("code","index")],value=min(x$value)))
)
#      code   index value
# HH11 HH11  023434  24.1
# HH45 HH45 3377477  37.2
# JL03 JL03 3388595  20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `dplyr` and `data.table` packages, you can do the following. You can get an index for the row having the minimum value for each group. You can use that in `slice()` if you use `dplyr`. You can achieve the same subsetting using `.SD` if you use `data.table`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dat %>%
group_by(code) %>%
slice(which.min(value))

#    code   index value
#  <fctr>  <fctr> <dbl>
#1   HH11  023434  24.1
#2   HH45 3377477  37.2
#3   JL03 1177777  20.0

setDT(dat)[, .SD[which.min(value)], by = code]

#   code   index value
#1: HH11  023434  24.1
#2: HH45 3377477  37.2
#3: JL03 1177777  20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few minutes more searching would have gotten me there... [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049359/1676356) seems to do the trick:

`merge(dat, aggregate(value ~ code, dat, min))`

Answer (score 0):

If you had added in the index variable that would have done it.

```
library(plyr)

# ddply
ddply(dat, .(code,index), summarise, val = min(value))

# base R
aggregate(value ~ code + index, dat, min)
```