# Aggregate a data frame while keeping other variables, with dplyr

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr, data-manipulation, summary

Suppose I have the following data frame (note the length of 'score'):

```
id = 1:10^8
school = LETTERS[1:10]
class = paste0(school, rep(1:10, each=10))
score = rnorm(10^8)

df = data.frame(id, school, class, score,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to compute the mean of each of the 100 classes. Yet, I also want
to keep the school variable in the results. Using dplyr:

```
df %>% group_by(class) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(score),
            school = unique(school))
```

This works, but is slow (8 seconds on my machine, and my data in fact is much bigger). I think one option could be not use unique() but a member of the join() family. But I need first to define another df as follow:

```
df_join = data.frame(class, school,
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and then:

```
df %>% group_by(class) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(score)) %>% 
    left_join(df_join)
```

This works and is less slow, as it takes now 6 seconds. Yet, creating the df_join here was easy because I invent the dataframe but in real life, obtaining the df_join can be much more challenging. So I would like to use only the original dataframe (df).

Any idea making this easier (and maybe faster) with dplyr? (I cheked there, but did not find a solution: [Aggregate by factor levels, keeping other variables in the resulting data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227223/aggregate-by-factor-levels-keeping-other-variables-in-the-resulting-data-frame))

Comment: Just use `df %>% group_by(school, class) %>% summarize(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only have one unique school per class, you can simply include the school variable in the grouping variables:

```
df %>% group_by(school, class) %>% summarize(mean_score = mean(score))
# # A tibble: 100 x 3
# # Groups:   school [?]
# school class mean_score
# <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 A      A1      0.000506
# 2 A      A10    -0.000275
# 3 A      A2      0.00136 
# 4 A      A3      0.000405
# 5 A      A4     -0.00156 
# 6 A      A5     -0.00214 
# 7 A      A6     -0.00108 
# 8 A      A7     -0.000534
# 9 A      A8      0.000804
# 10 A      A9      0.00106 
# # ... with 90 more rows
```

Here's a data.table equivalent:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = c("school", "class"))
df[, .(mean_score = mean(score)), by=.(school, class)]
```

Comment: Thanks. But grouping by an additional variable will slower the process. Although your approach is faster than using unique(), but it is slower than the join() I used.

Comment: @Rtist, if you're concerned with speed, you should switch to `data.table`