# In R, how to select rows based on a statistic of a column attribute?

Tags: r, cluster-computing, extract, rows

My table has thousands of rows  classified by 400 classes, and a dozen columns.

The ideal outcome will be a table with 400 rows (1 row for each class) based on the max value of column "z", and containing all the original columns.

Here is an example of my data, and I need only the 2nd, 4th, 7th, 8th rows extracted in this example, using R.

> ```
>      x           y         z    cluster 
> 1  712521.75  3637426.49  19.46   12 
> 2  712520.69  3637426.47  19.66   12  *
> 3  712518.88  3637426.63  17.37   225
> 4  712518.4   3637426.48  19.42   225 *
> 5  712517.11  3637426.51  18.81   225
> 6  712515.7   3637426.58  17.8    17 
> 7  712514.68  3637426.55  18.16   17  *
> 8  712513.58  3637426.55  18.23   50  *
> 9  712512.1   3637426.62  17.24   50
> 10 712513.93  3637426.88  18.08   50
> ```

I have tried many different combinations including these:

> ```
>   tapply(data$z, data$cluster, max)       # returns only the max value and cluster columns
>   which.max(data$z)         # returns only the index of the max value in the entire table
> ```

I have also read through the plyr package, but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help!   **aggregate()** and **merge()** worked perfectly for me.

An important point: **aggregate()** - selected only one of the duplicate points per cluster but, **merge()** - selected all duplicate points, since they had same max values in one cluster.

This is ideal in this case since the these points are 3D, and are not duplicates when considering x and y coordinates.

Here is my solution:

> ```
> df        <- read.table("data.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",")
> attach(df)
> names(df)
> [1] "Row"         "x"           "y"           "z"           "cluster"
> ```

```
head(df)
  Row        x       y     z     cluster
1   1 712521.8 3637426 19.46         361
2   2 712520.7 3637426 19.66         361
3   3 712518.9 3637427 17.37         147
4   4 712518.4 3637426 19.42         147
5   5 712517.1 3637427 18.81         147
6   6 712515.7 3637427 17.80          42


new_table_a     <- aggregate(z ~ cluster, df, max)  # output 400 rows, no duplicates
new_table_b     <- merge(new_table_a, df)          # output 408 rows, includes duplicates of "z"

head(new_table_b)
      cluster     z  Row        x       y
1           1 20.44 6043 712416.2 3637478
2          10 26.09 1138 712458.4 3637511
3         100 19.39 6496 712423.4 3637485
4         101 25.74 2141 712521.2 3637488
5         102 17.33 2320 712508.2 3637484
6         103 21.01 6908 712462.2 3637493
```

Answer (score 2):

A very straightforward way is to use `aggregate` and `merge`:

```
> merge(aggregate(z ~ cluster, mydf, max), mydf)
  cluster     z        x       y
1      12 19.66 712520.7 3637426
2      17 18.16 712514.7 3637427
3     225 19.42 712518.4 3637426
4      50 18.23 712513.6 3637427
```

---

You can even use the output of your `tapply` code to get what you need. Just make it into a `data.frame` instead of a named vector.

```
> merge(mydf, data.frame(z = with(mydf, tapply(z, cluster, max))))
      z        x       y cluster
1 18.16 712514.7 3637427      17
2 18.23 712513.6 3637427      50
3 19.42 712518.4 3637426     225
4 19.66 712520.7 3637426      12
```

---

For several more options, see the answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14048739/1270695).

Comment: Just a warning:  make sure you use `stats::aggregate` and not `raster::aggregate`.  (Ditto for `merge`).  Under normal circumstances this is unlikely to be a problem; but it might fool you one day :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, aggregate() and merge() worked perfect. The second example using tapply() did not work in my case, and produces an unseasonably large table. It is good to mention that aggregate() does not keep duplicate values and merge does,

Comment: @Inga, I don't totally understand your comment here, but my instinct says that you may want to read the help file for `merge` for how to control it better. In particular, the `by` argument (which specifies which columns to use as the columns to match against from each dataset) should be of use here to control the duplicate values. Good luck, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you Ananda! I tried to use the 'by', 'by.x' and 'by.y' but neither removed the duplicates. This is a good thing in my case since these values are just on the same z plane, and have different x,y. I also read the documentation on 'aggregate()' and it does not mention how duplicate are handled, that's why I wanted to point it out.