# RScript and statistics to find min

Tags: r, rscript

I need to find the minimum of following:

```
  Product Year
   N1     1988
   N2     1986
   N1     2008
   N1     2008
   N2     1999
   N2     2007
```

I want to find which year product first listed using RScript. For example product N1 was first listed in the year 1988. Product N2 was first listed in 1986. Similarly I have to do for 500000 products.

Comment: What did you try?  What did you search for?

Answer (score 3):

There are different possbilities: `aggregate`, `tapply`, or `by`.

```
dat <- read.table(text = " Product Year
   N1     1988
   N2     1986
   N1     2008
   N1     2008
   N2     1999
   N2     2007", header = TRUE)

aggregate(Year ~ Product, dat, min)
  Product Year
1      N1 1988
2      N2 1986

with(dat, tapply(Year, Product, min))
  N1   N2 
1988 1986 

with(dat, by(Year, Product, min))
Product: N1
[1] 1988
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Product: N2
[1] 1986
```

Comment: `library(plyr); ddply(dd,"Product",summarise,minYear=min(Year))`

Comment: Just curious: do you see a reason to prefer one of these? (Alternatively, I could ask as a new question, if that's better.)

Comment: I believe there are a variety of questions already on SO that do benchmarking on these options, plus `data.table` solutions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048739/r-use-ddply-or-aggregate/14048849#14048849

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty trivial to do in R.  Try:

```
dframe = read.table(text=" Product Year
   N1     1988
   N2     1986
   N1     2008
   N1     2008
   N2     1999
   N2     2007", header=T)

lapply(split(dframe$Year, dframe$Product), FUN=min)
$N1
[1] 1988

$N2
[1] 1986
```

The key functions here are [?split](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/split.html) and [?lapply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html).  `split()` breaks up the data frame by the product groups and returns a list of lists.  `lapply()` applies the function `min()` to each of those lists, and returns the output indexed by the list (product) in question.